# Not able to add items to a list in flutter

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

I was trying to create a list such that i can access it anywhere.So i created a class and in that i created a empty list .But when i try to add item in that from outside through the function inside the class it doesnt get added.It prints like its added but it isnt .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class PlaybackQueue{
  List<String > playbackQueue = <String>[];
 addToQueue(value)async{
     playbackQueue.add(value);
  //  playbackQueue.insert(0,"value"); // also tried this but this doesnt work too
 //print(value);
    print(playbackQueue.length);
    print(playbackQueue.first + "yih");
    print(PlaybackQueue().playbackQueue);
}
removeFirstElement(){
   playbackQueue.removeAt(0);
}
clearQueue(){
   playbackQueue.clear();
}
}

class PlaybackQueueView extends StatefulWidget {
 const  PlaybackQueueView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlaybackQueueView> createState() => _PlaybackQueueViewState();
}

class _PlaybackQueueViewState extends State<PlaybackQueueView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:const Text("PLAYBACK QUEUE"),),
      body: Container(color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(children: [
          if(PlaybackQueue().playbackQueue.isNotEmpty == true)
          for(int i = 0 ; i <  PlaybackQueue().playbackQueue.length ; i++ )
            Text(PlaybackQueue().playbackQueue.elementAt(i)),
          FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){

               PlaybackQueue().addToQueue('value');
          },)
        ],),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my console

```
I/flutter ( 7546): 1
I/flutter ( 7546): valueyih
I/flutter ( 7546): []
```

Comment: everywhere you write `PlaybackQueue()` you create a new instance of it. each with its own internal list

Comment: so , how should  i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're using `PlaybackQueue()`, a new instance of your object is created.

You can either instantiate your PlaybackQueue object in your initState method like so

```
 late PlaybackQueue playbackQueue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    playbackQueue = PlaybackQueue();
  }
```

and then in your widget Tree, use the `playbackQueue` variable.

Another solution would be to use the [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package to register your `PlaybackQueue` as a Singleton and use a single instance across your whole app.
Consider using this solution if this model must be accessed from multiple widgets.

**Example using GetIt :**
1- Register your Singleton in your `main.dart` file

```
final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

void main() {
  getIt.registerSingleton(PlaybackQueue());

  ...
  //Rest of your main() code
}
```

2- In your Widgets

```
late PlaybackQueue playbackQueue = getIt.get();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    playbackQueue.yourMethod();
    ...
  }
```

Comment: when registering playbackQueue i have to register every fuction or the whole class?

Comment: i tried it like this `final playbackQueue = GetIt.instance;
void setup(){
 playbackQueue.registerLazySingleton(() => PlaybackQueue());
}`  and then in the onpress call -`playbackQueue.get();` but how to i call the functions inside it ?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of GetIt usage. Looking at your questions, it looks like you're at the very beginning of your development's learning. You should first focus on learning how oriented object programming works before going further in your app's development.

Comment: yes it worked . and i am learning flutter .                                  thankyou for your help.                                                                    how can i be better at flutter, any tips or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method inside `setState()` method , that will add the item.

Comment: but i need it to call this from anywhere in my app.